# Managing multiple codeigniter applications

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have a two codeigniter applications in **example.com/1/** and **example.com/2/**
.I want to load one of them as default when a user access example.com and the other one should be also accessible  with full url.
what is the proper method to do it.?
is redirecting the user to the default app in .htaccess file and keep the applications separate SEO friendly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by renaiming your second application's folders.

```
 application
 system
 index.php
 application2
 system2
 index2.php
```

Then in index2.php :

```
$system_path = 'system2';
$application_folder = 'application2';
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

Comment: also Application1 and Application2 could share the same system folder.